# How to perform basic math on numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial, numpy-ndarray

So, I have a numpy ndarray with dimensions (984, 1977, 2). What I want to accomplish is to have a numpy ndarray where I do basic math on the final values. So let's say `data` is my ndarray. And `data[0][0]` equals to [72 46]. So I want to perform (72 - 46) / (72 + 46) and store that value in my new ndarray for each of the pair. Basically, it represents two stacked bands and the final output needs to be a resultant of the two based on the above formula (not NDVI). I have been looking at numpy's tutorial to find an answer but no luck so far.

Comment: Something like `data[:,:,0] - data[:,:,1]`?

Comment: Scratch my previous comment, that does the trick.

Comment: @Barmar since you gave the answer first, I would like to accept it as the answer but can't seem to do it here.

Comment: I don't use numpy, I wasn't actually sure it would work. I'm fine to let someone else have the credit, esp. since they coded it cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that array

```
x = data[:,:,0]
y = data[:,:,1]
```

are the two 'last' column values

```
res = (x-y)/(x+y)
```

should be the result you want for all pairs, a (984, 1977) shape array.